# How to get time mode in swift 12hr vs 24hr from device

Tags: ios, swift

Question is rather simple.  I'm  trying to figure how to tell what time format the current device  is in. I'm assuming its something simple like with languages -> Local.current.languageCode.  When  I search I keep getting results for conversions.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a date format from a template passing `"j"` and `.current` locale. If the resulting format contains the letter `"a"` means that the date format for that specific locale is set to 12 hours:

---

```
extension Locale {
    var is24Hour: Bool {
        DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "j", options: 0, locale: self)?.contains("a") == false
    }
}
```

---

Playground testing:

```
if Locale.current.is24Hour {
    print("Current setting is 24h")
} else {
    print("Current setting is 12h")
}
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
```

---

This will print:

> Current setting is 12h
> 10:09 PM